Restrict access to specific sheets in a Google Sheets documents
I have a Google Sheets document with 20 sheets. I need each user to have access to a specific sheet. For example, user example@gmail.com should only be able to access sheet 2, user example2@gmail.com should only have access to the sheet 3 etc. Here is what I have tried:
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheetsToHide = [
   "sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"
  ];
  
  Logger.log('Active user: ' + user);  // Логируем email активного пользователя


  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    Logger.log('Processing sheet: ' + sheetName);  // Логируем обрабатываемый лист


    // Удаляем существующую защиту сначала
    var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
    protections.forEach(function(protection) {
      protection.remove();
    });


    if ((user === "example@gmail.com" && (sheetName === "name1" || sheetName === "пустой")) || 
        (user === "user2@example.com" && sheetName === "Sheet2")) {
      Logger.log('Showing sheet: ' + sheetName);  // Логируем показ листа
      sheet.showSheet();
    } else if (sheetsToHide.includes(sheetName)) {
      Logger.log('Hiding sheet: ' + sheetName);  // Логируем скрытие листа
      sheet.hideSheet();


      // Применяем защиту на лист
      var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protected sheet');
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);  // Разрешаем владельцу скрипта редактировать
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors().filter(function(editor) {
        return editor.getEmail() !== me.getEmail();
      }));


      if (user === "example@gmail.com") {
        protection.removeEditor(user); 
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('Leaving sheet as is: ' + sheetName);  // Логируем оставление листа без изменений
      sheet.showSheet();  // Убедитесь, что другие листы видимы
    }
  });
}


It would be helpful if you can add more context as to what portion of the use case is giving you trouble.
My understanding is that the main question is about handling the many users and sheets that are involved, as I see your example has "hardcoded" the checks.
I made a proof of concept that I hope proves useful:
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const accessess = [
  {'email': 'aaa@example.com', 'allowedSheets':['Sheet1']},
  {'email': 'aab@example.com', 'allowedSheets':['Sheet2']},
  {'email': 'aac@example.com', 'allowedSheets':['Sheet3']}
];


function onOpen(e) {
  console.log('User %s opened the spreadsheet.', user);
  
  sheets.forEach((sheet) => {
    let sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    
    //clear existing sheet protections.
    let protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET); 
    protections.forEach((protection) => {
      protection.remove(); 
    });
    
    
    //grant all editors access.
    let usersWithAccess = []; 
    accessess.forEach((accessObject) => {
      if(accessObject.allowedSheets.includes(sheetName)) {
      usersWithAccess.push(accessObject.email);
      sheet.protect().addEditor(accessObject.email);
      console.log('Access granted to: %s', accessObject.email);
      }
    });
    
    
    //shows the sheet if the active user has access. 
    if(usersWithAccess.includes(user)) {
        sheet.showSheet();
      } else {
        sheet.hideSheet();
      }
    });
 }

There are still problems with this approach.

Performance, the function takes a couple of seconds to run, during which protections are modified and sheets shown.
Several users opening the spreadsheet at the same time. The hidden / shown sheets are set for all users.

So if user a opens the spreadsheet, their sheet becomes visible.
If during the same time user b opens the spreadsheet, user a's sheet will be hidden and both users will view user b's sheet. So I would avoid doing this.
A workaround for the first one could be to instead have a time driven trigger that keeps the protections up to date, independent from the onOpen event.
However, I'm assuming the reason you are trying to hide the sheets is because the users should not view the information they don't have access to.
If this is the case, another approach should be taken altogether.
As protections are not meant  to hide information, simply prevent users from editting it.
If users are not meant to view the information in sheets they don't have access to, I would instead recommend making each sheet its own spreadsheet.
